# Convert feature class to raster based on attribute field values

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, convert

As part of a tool, I’m trying to convert a feature class to a raster based on attribute field values.  I have accomplished this conversion using IRasterConvertHelper, but this is done without specifying an attribute field.  So I then was able to do the conversion using the IGeoProcessor to execute ConversionTools.FeatureToRaster , but was only able to use numeric fields (i.e., tool didn’t work when a text field was selected).

Going another route, I tried dissolving the feature class based on a selected attribute field using IBasicGeoprocessor and Dissolve, but this fails with:
{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.  (thanks ESRI, lots of help!)

Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish the same thing as the ArcToolbox Conversion Tools Feature to Raster tool and convert a feature class into a raster based on an attribute field?

Comment: Using IRasterConvertHelper and its ToRaster1 function, I have been able to complete this task using a numeric field (integer and decimal).  Unfortunately the code doesn’t want to work with a text field and returns the error message:  Item width must be greater than 0.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've never heard of a raster whose values are strings.  Instead, I think summarizing the string values into an integer code, then using the codes to apply labels to an [IRasterUniqueValueRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000pss000000)

Answer (score 1):

1. For each feature in FeatureClass, add the value from the specified field to an IDictionary; it may help to create another collection to hold the records in reverse order, so both keys and values are accessible (IDictionary)
2. IFeatureClassDecscriptor.Create ( FeatureClass as IGeoDataset, ……)
3. IRaster = IRasterConvertHelper.ToRaster1(FeatureClassDescriptor as IGeoDataset, ……)
4. IRasterDataset =  IConversionOp.ToRasterDataset (IGeoDataset, format, out_workspace, …..)
5. IRaster2 = IRasterDataset.CreateDefaultRaster()
6. ITable = IRaster2. AttribuateTable
7. ITable.AddField(new_IField)
8. ICursor = ITable.Search
9. IRow = pCursor.NextRow
10. IRow.set_Value(….)